# How to define string name as class in java

Tags: jackson

I am using Jackson parser for JSON parsing in android app. The JSON data is in following form

```
data: {
train_number: "12951",
chart_prepared: false,
class: "2A"
}
```

How to parse property with **class** name in Java?
Please, help me.

Comment: how to declare field name as "class" which supposed to be type String in java

String class = "Hello";

it is giving error in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning - your JSON is not valid. It should look like this:

```
{"train_number":1,"chart_prepared":false,"class":"2A"}
```

You can change default name property using [`@JsonProperty`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonProperty.html) annotation.
Your POJO class should looks like that:

```
class Data {

    private int train_number;
    private boolean chart_prepared;

    @JsonProperty(value = "class")
    private String clazz;

    ...
}
```

Now you can build simple test method:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setTrain_number(1);
        data.setClazz("2A");

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data);
        System.out.println(json);

        System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(json, Data.class));
    }
}
```

Above program prints:

```
{"train_number":1,"chart_prepared":false,"class":"2A"}
Data [train_number=1, chart_prepared=false, clazz=2A]
```

Comment: yeah it was helpful to resolve my problem in which i was stuck for two days. thanks a lot

Comment: please help me if you can for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168528/detect-location-at-regular-interval-in-android-and-show-notification-when-locati